# Output hml5 canvas element as html page

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

Recently I got a task which is to generate html page based on user interaction(This is completely a webapp). User can interact through the web browser to create a template and save template . I know it is pretty simple.

But the problem comes when I have to allow the users to change the div size,content size, image size etc dynamically(using mouse movements) also user can drag drop image to html etc. As I thought it is difficult to develop the entire thing using html5 and jquery it did some googling and found the html5 canvas can do all these job (we can drag drop, change size etc ). Only thing which I found difficult is export it as an html5 document. Is it possible to convert the canvas element a html5 document.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to let users to customize templates on a canvas and then export the drawing as a HTML5 document with `div`, `span` and all the other tag soup. As far as I know, there's no easy way to do it. So the short answer is no, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here i added the sample code for draw a image using canvas in html5 page. Please check the sample code. Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```